# Doctrine: Handling monthly data

Tags: database-design, symfony, doctrine

I am developing an application using **Symfony2** and **Doctrine2**. I have many tables that store monthly data. In general I define entities like so:

```
class Entity {
    private $atribute1;
    // ...
    private $atributeN;

    private $year;
    private $month;
    private $value;
}
```

I have some scenarios where an entity stores monthly data related to another entity. Eg: **Product - Order** association:

```
class Product {
    private $name;
    // ...
}

class Order {
    /**
     * ORM\ManyToOne(TargetEntity="Product")
     * ...
     */
    private $product;

    private $year;
    private $month;
    private $value;
}
```

In these scenarios, the data is entered in a tabular form where the user specifies for each product the corresponding values for the 12 months of the year.

My question is: **Is not better to design the value table (eg. Order) denormalized in the following way:**

```
class Order {
    /**
     * ORM\ManyToOne(TargetEntity="Product")
     * ...
     */
    private $product;

    private $year;

    // Value for january
    private $month1Value;

    // Value for february
    private $month2Value;

    //...

    // Value for december
    private $month12Value;
}
```

We specify the product values in one record (instead of many records).
I think that this design would simplify persistence of values and most important the retrieval of product values.
Otherwise I will need to write code to do transformations for displaying the product values for each month.

**SOME NOTES:**

- The users/stakeholders are just interested in the total values (sum of the 12 months values)
- There will not be any need to make a query with a filter by an interval of months.
- The product values must be shown in a table with header: PRODUCT, JAN VALUE, FEB VALUE, ... DEC VALUE.
- **I understand that normalization is fundamental, but I also know that we should denormalize sometimes when necessary (for performance reasons, design, etc)**

I am using Symfony2 and Doctrine, but the my question is not tied to these frameworks.

Comment: It is not better unless you have a performance issue.  And you can't really know that until your database is at a reasonable production size.